# How to "if true, hide label text" in react storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook

As above, if hideText is 'True', 'label' text will be disabled and not shown in my button. How to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your code but you can generally use ternary operators within jsx.

So where you have your text and want to only show it when the hideText is false you can do a simple condition:
{ hideText ? (null) : (text) }

so 'hideText ?' evaluates the value of hideText variable/state. Then you have (return value if true) : (return value if false).

Comment: I did a ternary operator but I am struggling to hide the text label, even at the CSS the label: null. It is because in the proptype it is defined as a string.